# How can I capture all data from a specific device on my network?

Tags: sniffer, monitoring, sniffing

I have an iPhone that is connected to my Wi-Fi at home. I want to capture ALL traffic from that iPhone (because it's my network) and record it and view it. I don't have physical access to the device.

My router is a basic Apple AirPort Extreme, so it doesn't have advanced capture features built into it.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can start with Wireshark. You will also need AirSnort or AiroPeek. For real advanced stuff check out KISMET.

Finally if you intention is non-intrusive, non-disruptive, you might want to use a TRIAL version of SolarWinds. I'm not sure as they have multiple utilities for various purposes. Check out SolarWinds web-site & make a wise choice for yourself. SOLARWINDS is a Paid software & costly too. You might get a Trialware for free initial 30 days.
Hope this helps,thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **arpspoof** and **Dsniff** to perform man in middle attack, (comes preinstalled with Kali Linux). with this you can capture all unencrypted trafic authentication ( ftp, telnet, HTTP, SNMP, POP, LDAP)

In order to see and grab traffic other than your own, you need to first put your wireless adaptor into promiscuous mode.

To capture Https trafic you need to install CA certificates in victim machine.

Answer (score -1):

You could perform a [Man In The Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack using a tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).